# How to rank based on a selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For a reservation I would like to calculate the price for extra_guests (e.g. guests not included in the price).

- Therefore, I would like to get all the guests for the reservation (`reservation_guests`). **Done**
- Get their age_table **Done**
- Rank the guests based on their age_tables' column `:rank`. **Issue**

The goal is to use the ranking to start calculating the extra_guest_price of the extra_guest with the lowest age_table ranking, in case there are guests not included in the standard reservation.

**Issue**

I just need a specific range of age_tables to rank based on `:rank`. My current set-up is wrong as I cannot use order on an array, but I'm not sure how to structure it to make it work.

```
def total_extra_guest_price(reservation, res_guest)
    sum_guest = 0
    sum_amount_guests = 0
    age_table_list = []
    reservation.reservation_extra_guests.each do |guest|
      sum_amount_guests += guest.extra_guest_quantity
    end

    # persons included vs persons reservation
     #if more persons
    if reservation.room.room_category.persons_included < sum_amount_guests

      #count number of too many persons
      extra_persons = sum_amount_guests - reservation.room.room_category.persons_included

      # iterate over extra_guests belonging to reservation to get age_tables
      reservation.reservation_extra_guests.each do |extra_guest_item|
        age_table_list << extra_guest_item.extra_guest.age_table
      end

      #rank age tables, so lowest rank can be used to calculate price. Issue!!!
      age_table_list.order(:rank)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear about your question so my suggestion may not be the best solution. But you can try the `sort_by()`

```
age_table_list.sort_by{ |age_table| age_table.rank }
```

read more [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort)

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for!